# Video capturing in Windows mobile app using Js

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows mobile app using Js  i want to capture video, compress it and  send it to server if front cam available from front cam i searched but i didn't found any proper documentation for js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Windows.Media.Capture API to capture video in a Windows Phone Runtime app from either JavaScript or .Net. See [Quickstart: capturing video using the MediaCapture API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx) and the [Media capture sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=241428) for full JavaScript sample code.

Once you've recorded the video you can upload it to a web service with the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient API. See [How to connect to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469430.aspx) for a walkthrough.

Comment: Hi now video gets recorded but there is oreintation issue ,that is the video is rotated